# What is the difference between adding months and converting months to seconds in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question that needs answering.

Current time is 7/1/2023 I want to display this date 14 months later.

There are 2 methods but they produce 2 different results, can you point out this difference?

Option 1: Convert 14 months to seconds and then add it to the current date

```
[22] pry(main)> (Time.zone.parse("1/7/2023") + 14.months.to_i).to_s
=> "2024-08-30 02:47:24 +0900"
```

Option 2: Add months directly to the current date

```
[23] pry(main)> (Time.zone.parse("1/7/2023") + 14.months).to_s
=> "2024-09-01 00:00:00 +0900"
```

Comment: Which one makes sense for your usage? That’s the answer that matters.

Comment: `14.months.to_i` doesn’t use the current month as a starting point. Instead, it uses the _average_ number of seconds in a month and multiplies that by 14. The `time + 14.months` variant however increments `time` by 14 actual months.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, Time.zone is not ruby function.

It come from rails https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone

`Time.zone.parse` will result `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

```rb
Time.zone.parse("1/7/2023").class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

so if we look into it class documentation, there is a `+` method

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-2B

if we see the documentation, it said

```
    # For instance, a time + 24.hours will advance exactly 24 hours, while a
    # time + 1.day will advance 23-25 hours, depending on the day.
    #
    #   now + 24.hours      # => Mon, 03 Nov 2014 00:26:28.725182881 EST -05:00
    #   now + 1.day         # => Mon, 03 Nov 2014 01:26:28.725182881 EST -05:00
```

looking on to that, 24.hours will advance exactly 24 hours, but 1.day it will advance to 23-25 hours. so if we use same logic, if we convert month to second, it will advance more accurate

```rb
irb(main):005:0> (Time.zone.parse("1/7/2023") + 14.months.to_i)
=> Fri, 30 Aug 2024 02:47:24.000000000 UTC +00:00
irb(main):006:0> Time.zone.parse("1/7/2023") + 14.months
=> Sun, 01 Sep 2024 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

please correct me if i am wrong, thanks

Comment: I agree with the majority of this post excepting *"...if we convert month to second, it will advance more accurate..."*. Integer.month is an estimated value. For instance over 48 months this value is between 30.0 and 30.4358974 days. Note: it is never 28 or 29 days nor does it reach 31 days. So conversion of this to seconds is not more accurate for advancing exactly N months. For a real world example: If your car payment is due by 23:59, the 1st of every month; using Integer.months.to_i, your actual payment times would deviate by -4.3 hours and 65.8 hours over 60 months.

Comment: i see, i never found that kind of case. thanks @engineersmnky

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::Duration` implements [`to_i`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-to_i) based on the assumption that 1 year equals 365.2425 days (the so-called "mean year") which is the average number of seconds when including leap years.

```
365.2425 * 24 * 60 * 60
#=> 31556952.0

1.year.to_i
#=> 31556952
```

`1.month.to_i` is 1/12th of that value:

```
1.year.to_i / 12
#=> 2629746

1.month.to_i
#=> 2629746
```

That value is equivalent to 30.436875 days or 30 days, 10 hours, 29 minutes and 6 seconds.

> What is the difference between adding months and converting months to seconds in Ruby?

Adding `1.month` increments only the time object's *month* value, leaving all other values (day, hour, minute, second) unchanged:

```
time = Time.utc(2024, 8, 30)
# => 2024-08-30 00:00:00 UTC

time + 1.month
#=> 2024-09-30 00:00:00 UTC
#        ^^
```

whereas adding `1.month.to_i` increments it by the above *average* value:

```
time + 1.month_to_i
#=> 2024-09-29 10:29:06 UTC
```

which is equivalent to:

```
time + 30.days + 10.hours + 29.minutes + 6.seconds
#=> 2024-09-29 10:29:06 UTC
```

The same applies to `14.month` vs. `14.months.to_i`, just by a factor of 14.